# How can I get network information from a Awesomium web view?

Tags: awesomium

I'm trying to find failures when loading an image or script via Awesomium WebView, but the console only seems to log Javascript errors. Are there ways to capture that data as well?

```
            webView.ConsoleMessage += ( s, e ) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format( "{0}: {1}, {2} | {3}: {4}", e.EventType, e.EventName, e.Message, e.Source, e.LineNumber ));
            };
```

Comment: sure ... its possible ... i have answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287040/how-to-get-httponly-cookies-from-awesomium/44411173#44411173

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ConsoleMessage`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=E_Awesomium_Core_IWebView_ConsoleMessage) occurs when a message is added to the console on the page. This is usually the result of a JavaScript error being encountered on a page or of messages added through *[`Console`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console)*.

Failures to load resources will fire a **[`LoadingFrameFailed`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=E_Awesomium_Core_IWebView_LoadingFrameFailed)** event. The event's arguments provide an [`ErrorDescription`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=P_Awesomium_Core_LoadingFrameFailedEventArgs_ErrorDescription) and an [`ErrorCode`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=P_Awesomium_Core_LoadingFrameFailedEventArgs_ErrorCode) of type **[`NetError`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=T_Awesomium_Core_NetError)**.