# How to get HttpOnly cookies from awesomium?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, awesomium

I want to get ALL cookies from the site, but most of them are HttpOnly.

JS does not work:

```
var cookie = webControl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.cookie;");
```

How to get HttpOnly cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you're trying to get Cookies back from Javascript? ...
the best opinion to get all Headers (including Cookies) is to use Awesomium with a Proxy written also in C# ...

Wiki: ProxyConfig
http://docs.awesomium.net/html/P_Awesomium_Core_WebPreferences_ProxyConfig.htm

Github C# Proxy:
https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy

Titanium has 2 useful Events:

```
proxyServer.BeforeRequest += OnRequest;
proxyServer.BeforeResponse += OnResponse;
```

a Simple implementation which gave you the SystemEventArgs is:

```
public async Task OnRequest(object sender, SessionEventArgs e)
public async Task OnResponse(object sender, SessionEventArgs e)
```

After implementation you have the possibilty to grap all Headers and delete or modifiy it :)

Hope it helps ...